# How to add my device (Galaxy s6 edge) to connected devices?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I am new here and it is my first question.
I downloaded Android Studio from official website then when i debugged the application ( Hello world) i can't find my device , and the device is connected to PC...Also troubleshoot "VT-x is disabled in BIOS" so i will be glad for you if you helped me.
Thanks..[image]

Photo from my PC...my android version is 6.0.1

Comment: Have you enabled the developer mode and USB-Debugging on your device?

Comment: I  don't think so.. How to enable them?

Comment: ok thanks...it worked now
Settings/About Device/Software Info/Build number << click on it 4 times

Comment: Then Settings/Developer Options/ Enable Debugging mode = true (Checked)

Comment: If you've solved your own problem, post an answer and then accept it, so that other visitors can see the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I am new be too.

Check your phone (Settings - Developer options(maybe You can not search this option, Settings - About Phone - touch more 5 build number) - check usb debugging.

The other word, Enable USB debugging options.

and also you must install USB Driver on your PC.